# Tailwind doesn't let second breakpoint works in Desktop-first

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind and changed the default behavior of responsive styling to Destop-first, by adding these to tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      ...
      screens: {
        '2xl': { max: '1536px' },
        xl: { max: '1280px' },
        lg: { max: '1024px' },
        md: { max: '768px' },
        sm: { max: '640px' },
        xs: { max: '480px' },
      },
    },
  },
```

When I use these breakpoints, it doesn't work at the smaller screen at the second (smaller) breakpoint. For example:

```
<h1 className="text-8xl leading-[120px] lg:text-7xl md:text-5xl">
    Lorem Ipsum
</h1>
```

will have this as in inspection: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfkmL.png)

So I wondered if any thing we can do to help this, or I need to use the default Mobile-first responsiveness of Tailwind in order to use many breakpoints.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: not sure about this, you might want to open an issue, anyway: also see tailwind's builtin [max-breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `tailwind.config.js` to:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      ...
      screens: {
        '2xl': '1536px',
        xl: '1280px',
        lg: '1024px',
        md: '768px',
        sm: '640px',
        xs: '480px',
      },
   },
 },
```

Read more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens)